# Zenoss SMS missing text

Tags: linux, zenoss, sms-gateway, at

I've set up a *Xenserver* hosting a *Debian VM* with *Zenoss Core 4.2.4*.
The Xenserver has a *Siemens T35 GSM Modem* attached to its serial port COM1.
I used *ser2net* + some Xenserver configuration to get it working. (COM1 binding, SELinux, ...)
I created a shell script that can easily send SMS messages.

I created a trigger + notification and everything works perfectly EXCEPT that the message is empty!!!

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# - VAR
set ctrlz \032
set xt \135
set timeout 15
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
set number [lindex $argv 2]
set message [lindex $argv 3]
# - LOG
log_file -a sms.log;
send_log "$host $port $number:$message"
# - CONNECT
spawn telnet $host $port
sleep 1
# - SEND
send AT+CMGF=1\r;
expect "OK"
send AT+CMGS="$number"\r;
expect ">"
send "$message$ctrlz";
expect "OK"
# - END
```

And here is the Zenoss Page Command:

```
$ZENHOME/bin/sms.sh 10.10.0.52 3333 $RECIPIENT
```

This works in Linux as follows:

```
./sms.sh 10.10.0.52 3333 +32486000000 message
```

I just can't get the **message** from Zenoss in the SMS message....
I need to complete this last step to get it fully working!

If I try sending a test message from Zenoss, it also arrives but with no text...

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Extra, updated the script to log what it's getting for parameters but this doesn't work when being called from Zenoss... I'm new to bash scripting btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working,

I looked in the `/usr/local/zenoss/Products/ZenUtils/Utils.py` file to find that
Zenoss sends the **message text** to `stdin` so I only needed to read stdin in the expect script to get the message.

Here is the **new** working script: (note that I left out host & port parameters)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# - VAR
set ctrlz \032
set xt \135
set timeout 15
set number [lindex $argv 0]
set message [gets stdin]
# - LOG
log_file -a sms.log;
send_log "$number:$message"
# - CONNECT
spawn telnet 10.10.0.52 3333
sleep 1
# - SEND
send AT+CMGF=1\r;
expect "OK"
send AT+CMGS="$number"\r;
expect ">"
send "$message$ctrlz";
expect "OK"
# - END
```

Hope this will help anyone!

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that from my understanding Zenoss sends the actual message to the scripts STDIN input, but your script expects it as a command line parameter. You have to modify your expect script in a way that it will read the message from STDIN instead of `$argv 3`. After that, your test script should work like this:

```
echo "Message" | ./sms.sh 10.10.0.52 3333 +32486000000
```

I don't really know expect, so I can't help with the actual script.

Comment: I know, I just figured this out myself but I can't answer my own question. Need +5 rep :(

Comment: lol, now I can't upvote yet... grrrr :)

Comment: @grmbl Now you can.

Answer (score 0):

`expect "&gt;"`? Is that some kind of copy-paste error or should that actually be `expect ">"`?

Comment: :) fixed the html character

Comment: Can you upvote my question, I need +5 rep to answer my own question and I have it in clipboard. :)

Comment: Upvoted. Have a nice day! :)